# How to consider the vehicle's antenna height according to Veins and SUMO?

Tags: veins, sumo

According to SUMO, the default vehicle height is 1.5m.
In Veins, I use `*.node[*].nic.phy80211p.antennaOffsetZ` to set the antenna height for the vehicle.
So, if I want to set the height of the antenna to 1.7m, should I include SUMO's default height (1.5m) in the height (1.7-1.5 = 0.2) or just set the parameter above to 1.7m?

Comment: Although I never used it myself I am fairly sure that veins does not care abut SUMO's  vehicle height, so please do the latter.

Comment: @Michael So, for reason SUMO include the height of the vehicle?

Comment: mainly for visualization of you use the 3D GUI